# Asset Library - How can I refresh the Preview Image?

Tags: asset-browser

Is there a way to refresh the preview image of an asset in the asset library?

[image]I tried to refreshing the asset library but it dind't make difference even though the object is place as desired inside the file.

All the transformations are aplied in the blend file?

Comment: I guess if it comes from another file (User Library) its thumbnail will depend on the way it is in this file?

Comment: @moonboots I guess the same but thats not the case here, as you can see in the screenshot. This is the issue - the thumbnail is not dependant on the way it is in the file.

Comment: I meant that if the object comes from another file through the User Library, you won't be able to change its thumbnail, unless you open the original file, have you tried that?

Comment: @moonboots I imported the objects into new blender file and marked them as assets myself, so they don't come from another file.

Comment: That's weird I've just tested and it should work, but what I see from your screenshot is that the refresh button is greyed, are you sure that you've selected the one that you've marked as asset and not the original one?

Comment: Also the Source should be Current File if you marked it as asset in the current file

Comment: Mmh ok actually I guess you just need to switch from User Library to Current Library and you'll find the thumbnail of the object, select it and refresh

Answer (score 3):

As we see in your screenshot, it's still the object from the *User Library* that is selected, if your object is now part of the current file assets, you need to select *Current File* instead:

[image]

Now the refresh button is available:

[image]

Comment: ah, I see, I need to open the file where the asset is marked and refresh the thumbnail from that file. Thanks:)

Comment: that was my first comment, but it was not clear, it all depends if you want to change the thumbnail of the original object or of the one you dropped down in your scene and marked as asset so that it's now part of the asset browser of the current file